# What is the difference between 発行する and 作成する when talking about documents?

Tags: word-choice

What would be the difference between **発行【はっこう】する** and **作成【さくせい】する** when talking about documents?　I will use both of them in the next sentence, could you please tell me if there is any difference?

> 不良品【ふりょうひん】の返品伝票【へんぴんでんぴょう】を**作成【さくせい】する**。
>
> 不良品の返品伝票を**発行【はっこう】する**。

Great thanks is advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare these two definitions:

> 計画や書類、また文章などを**作る**こと。
>   — [さくせい【作成】の意味 - goo国語辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/86983/meaning/m0u/%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90/)
>
> 紙幣・債券・証明書・定期券・入場券などを**作って、通用させる**こと。
>   — [はっこう【発行】の意味 - goo国語辞書](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/177409/meaning/m0u/)

発行 is more explicit in saying that the document is not just *created* but also *made effective*, often in an official or somewhat irrevocable way.

In actual use, 作成 can **imply** that the document was also made effective, but you can't be sure without additional context.

In terms of 伝票, a simple distinction would be:

1. 返品伝票を**作成**する = *create* a return slip
2. 返品伝票を**発行**する = *issue* a return slip

For example, I can imagine an app where you click the 作成 button to create a new slip, and when you're done filling it out, click the 発行 button to print/send it. (But of course, since 発行 includes the notion of 作成, there could also be an app where a single 発行 button both creates and prints the new slip.)

Answer (score 1):

From jisho.org

[発行{はっこう}する](http://jisho.org/search/%E7%99%BA%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)- To publish(a newspaper,magazine, general public consumption material) which is expected to be consumed(read) by a large number of people.

[作成{さくせい}する](http://jisho.org/search/%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B)- To write/draw up a *legal* document. Meant for a specific(small) group of people and serving a very specific purpose(defining the scope/boundary/will of event/s or person/s)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

発行 = to issue, to circulate ( usually in large quantities)
作成 = to create, to compose

小説を作成して 発行をします。
After writing the novel, I will publish it